# Assigning values to a vector in a loop (R)

Tags: r, loops, matrix, vector

I have a matrix:

```
x1j1 = c(6,6,18,8,11,34,28,71,43,33,20)
x1j2 = c(27,23, 64,44,30,75,26,124,54,30,14)
x2j1 = c(25,28,36,35,15,44,42,54,34,29,39)
x2j2 = c(15,13,22,29,31,64,30,64,56,20,21)

x61 = cbind(x1j1,x1j2,x2j1,x2j2)
```

I need to find differences of elements of x1j1-x2j1 and of x2j1-x2j2.

The code I have is:

```
dj1 = c()
dj2 = c()

for (i in 1:nrow(x61)) {
    dj1 <- x1j1[i] - x2j1[i]
    dj2 <- x1j2[i] - x2j2[i]
}
```

The answer I am getting though is only a difference between the first elements:

```
> dj1
[1] -19
> dj2
[1] -7
```

How do I create vectors with differences of according values?

Answer (score 2):

You actually already know how (although your code uses different variables, so there is no consistency):

```
x1j1 - x2j1
#  [1] -19 -22 -18 -27  -4 -10 -14  17   9   4 -19
x2j1 - x2j2
#  [1]  10  15  14   6 -16 -20  12 -10 -22   9  18
```

That is because subtraction is a *vectorized* operation in R, meaning that it allows to work with vectors directly.

For learning purposes, the loop could be written as follows

```
dj1 <- dj2 <- numeric(nrow(x61))

for (i in 1:nrow(x61)) {
  dj1[i] <- x1j1[i] - x2j1[i]
  dj2[i] <- x1j2[i] - x2j2[i]
}
```

I defined `dj1` and `dj2` as empty vectors of prespecified length (for efficiency). Then, just like you use `x1j1[i]` to look at a certain element, you need to use `dj1[i]` to update a certain element.

Comment: @FeyziBagirov, does it answer your question?